# Why is a featured post also under the "Frequently Asked" heading?

Tags: discussion

I'm sure for some reason this is [working-as-designed], but I'm interested to understand why. Is the below scenario because of the often used "burninate" keyword?

[image]

Comment: The description is quite accurate. Requests to burninate a tag are pretty much the most frequently asked question around here.

Comment: That's true @Cody, but I wonder if the intent of the Frequently Asked section is to offer a list of canonical questions, in which case a broader discussion on the burninate process is more appropriate than a single tag thread.

Comment: But the real question is, Should we burniate [friendship]?  I mean, should we?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It has nothing to do with [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request); the relevant tag for this behavior is [featured](/questions/tagged/featured).

Both [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) and [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) have the same special visibility rules.  Notably, both appear in the community bulletin and in a special sidebar.  According to [jadarnel27's answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134961/how-is-a-featured-question-frequently-asked/134977#134977), both tags are treated the same way.  It's just that the heading for the sidebar is "Frequently Asked" because anything longer would wrap the heading to another line.  Feel free to suggest a better label for that section, but since featured posts aren't very common I personally don't think it's a big deal.

Comment: Good find, [your linked MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134961/how-is-a-featured-question-frequently-asked/134977#134977) looks to be a cross-site dupe.

Comment: Indeed.  But since I couldn't find a duplicate here on MSO, I decided to answer it here.

Comment: In light of new information, I will soon submit a Feature-Request to rename that section "Special Sidebar" /s

Comment: What's the point of including [tag:featured] in that section, when it has it's own "Featured on Meta" section already?

Comment: No idea.  Could be a holdover.

Comment: @OrangeDog there's not "featured" function for anonymous users.